# Spring junit ignore application context errors

Tags: java, spring, junit

I am using spring for my application , and recently i added a bean with some default values to an application context file, lets say contextA.xml.  The way the application is layered is , ContextA.xml refers to bean which is in ContextB.xml and beans in ContextB.xml is referring to beans in ContextC.xml etch and goes like that.

I would like to write a small unit test for the bean which I added in ContextA.xml.  Is there any way I can do this by not loading the entire xml files in my unit test. My goal is to test the default value of a bean I added in contextA.xml.

Is there any way to ignore the errors and continue to load the beans , that way I can test my bean ?

Comment: Don't initialize a spring context at all. Just instnatiate your bean as a pojo yourself. Alternatively instantiate a spring context that is just the bean you're testing and its dependencies.

Comment: If it is a unit test then test only the unit by not loading the context.